# WPF: How to bind together two properties bound to two different controls

Tags: wpf, multibinding

Suppose I have 2 properties `CantTouchThis.First` and `CantTouchThis.Second`  where `CantTouchThis` means I cannot hook into their `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

I can bind them to two sliders:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding CantTouchThis.First, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Slider Value="{Binding CantTouchThis.Second, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<!-- textblocks just to display the values -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CantTouchThis.First, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CantTouchThis.Second, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" />
```

How can I create a checkbox that (if checked) will bind the two sliders and `CantTouchThis.First` and `CantTouchThis.Second` together?

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Bind both together." Name="bindUsCheckbox" />
```

Help always appreciated,

Mark

**EDIT**

I started trying to accomplish this using an `IMultiValueConverter` but got stuck when trying to make it conditional on the checkbox:

```
public class DuplicateValuesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        object[] output = new object[2];
        output[0] = value;
        output[1] = value;         

        return output;
    }
}
```

and a binding like this:

```
        <Slider.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource magicConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding Path="First" />
                <Binding Path="Second" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Slider.Value>
```

Comment: How do you want the multibinding to work? Do you want the values aggregated (added)?

Comment: Nope just duplicated,  ie First == Second == Slider1.Value == Slider2.Value    The solution doesn't have to be an `IMultiValueConverter` but it may be possible to use one in this case?

Comment: [You need a DataTrigger](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) for this - the trigger is evaluated when the value of the IsChecked property on the CheckBox changes.

Comment: A DataTrigger that changes the Binding from a regular Binding to a MultiBinding?

Comment: The approach you take depends on the complexity of what you want to achieve - you might want to swap out a templated area/style based on the checkbox value.

Answer (score 1):

Include the checkbox.IsChecked value in your MultiBinding. Use the converterParameter to identify which slider it is and return the value of it when not sync.

```
<Slider.Value>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource magicConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" ConverterParamter='0'>
        <Binding Path="First" />
        <Binding Path="Second" />
        <Binding ElementName="bindUsCheckbox" Path="IsChecked" />
   </MultiBinding>
</Slider.Value>
```

And handle it like this:

```
public class DuplicateValuesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(value[2].ToString()))
        { // keep sync
            return values[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return values[int.Parse(parameter.ToString())];
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] output = new object[2];
        output[0] = value;
        output[1] = value;         

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work either, it just binds the two sliders together.  As an example: You move slider #1, changing its value, it fires the `ConvertBack` and assigns both `First` and `Second` to its value.  After that it does the `Convert` with the conditional statement but by that point it doesn't matter.  Still a pretty neat attempt.

Comment: What if you only set the value in the ConvertBack to the output[parameter]? Would that only set the value from the slider-change to the CantTouchThis.First or CantTouchThis.Second Property and then after the PropertyChangedEvent fire the Convert and set the value depended on the checkBox.IsChecked to both (if sync) or only to slider originaly changed.